# asp.net: dynamically extend content

Tags: asp.net, dynamic

i'm not sure how to call that. i'm looking for some samples guiding me how to implement a automatic page extend. i'm mean something like the friends list on facebook. first only a few friends are loaded. after you scroll down, some others get loaded.

thx in advance

Comment: WebForms or MVC? And I believe it is called an infinite list.

Comment: webforms. infinite list sounds applicable.. i will take a look at it

Comment: sry, i'm new to stackoverflow. just did my work :) but found nothing worthy on infinite list for asp :(

Comment: you didn't find anything because A. That's probably not what people tend to refer to that feature as. B. The feature is ambiguous between technologies and C. It's mostly made up of javascript or (insert your js library here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem relies more on AJAX then anything else.

I suggest using jQuery Ajax, and here is a nice article that will get you started with calling ASP.NET web services via client side script.
[enter link description here](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

If you don't have experience using ajax this will probably be a lot for you to grasp. Especially if you're going to dive in with a feature like you described above.

**Edit:** It may be more practical to use a plugin to achieve this:
[scrolling jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/scrolling)

Comment: i thought this would be a common problem. however, i'm not new to ajax, but i think there are so much ways how to complete this task. and i want to do it right.

Comment: @eric cartman I edited my post with a link to jQuery plugin that you may find useful.

Comment: **infinite scroll** is the keyword i was looking for! thanks to both of you. also found this [link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b8381915-06d9-4538-b4bb-5ac2a8e73f34/implementing-continuous-s.aspx) interesting